# Imagick results in negative image while using imagick::profileImage

Tags: php, imagick

I m using PHP's Imagick extension to manipulate images. Following are my code

```
try{
    $sourceimg=dirname(__FILE__)."\\source.jpg";
    $destinationimg=dirname(__FILE__)."\\source_cmyk.tiff";
    $im=new Imagick();
    $im->setResolution(300,300);
    $im->readImage($sourceimg);
    $im->setImageColorSpace(imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
    $im->stripImage();
    $cmykprofile=@file_get_contents("C:\\USWebUncoated.icc");
    $im->profileImage("icm",$cmykprofile);
    $im->setImageDepth(8);
    $im->setImageUnits(1); //0=undefined, 1=pixelsperInch, 2=PixelsPerCentimeter
    $im->setResolution(300,300); //set output resolution to 300 dpi
    $im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
    $im->writeImage($destinationimg);

}catch(ImagickException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The problem i m having is the code negates the original Image. This issue occurs only if i use `$im->profileImage`. What will be the cause for this? And how to solve this issue? The profile i m using is cmyk color profile that i downloaded from http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=3680

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using images with specialized color profiles or non-RGB images (e.g. CMYK JPEG), you should convert them to sRGB first.

With striping profile you strip **ICC color profile** as well. Most browsers display your stripped image with gamma 2.2 (default), which differs from CMYK.

Solution of your problem is in user contributed note here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php